# Getting difficulty in loading image in react django project

Tags: django, reactjs, image-loading

Have tried all available solutions. My settings.py is here

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

Home.js file, which is the front end home page is here

```
<Image
              bordered
              rounded
              size="large"
              src={"/static/2461.jpg"}
            />
            <div>
              <img src={'/static/2461.jpg'} />

            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={'/static/https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDg2YTI0YmQtYzgwMi00Zjk4LWJkZjgtYjg0ZDE2ODUzY2R'} />

            </div>
```

and have placed assets folder topmost in the hierarchy. I would be helpful if someone can help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: firstly  use {% load static %} tag at the start of your template, secondly you need `%` in your tag. You can read more about static file in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Do u mean to paste {% load static %} in the same file (template).

Comment: Pasting {% load static %} in the  same file gives the error " ; expected ".